# How do I solve this Cauchy problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 2 \frac{ \partial u}{\partial y} = 1 + u $

Where $ u = \sin x$ on $ y = 3x+1 $

Working out so far

$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{2} = \frac{du}{1+u}$

Integrating dx and dy gives $c_1 = 2x - y $

I'm not sure how to calculate $c_2$?  Do you integrate dx and du or dy and du?

Comment: You can either 1) follow the exact same procedure we went through in your other question, 2) integrate $dx$ and $du$ 3) integrate $dy$ and $du$.

Comment: I get c2 = x(1+u) - u , is this correct?

Comment: No, it isn't. Using $dx, du$, I get $$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{du}{u+1} \implies \ln (u+1) = x + c_{2} \implies u+1 = c_{2} e^{x}$$

Comment: How do you find a ratio between c1 and c2 with that value of c2? For when your applying the boundary conditions

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 2 \frac{ \partial u}{\partial y} = 1 + u $$
On the characteristic curves : 
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2}=\frac{du}{u+1}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2}$ :
$$2x-y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{u+1}$ :
$$(u+1)e^{-x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$(u+1)e^{-x}=F(2x-y)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$u(x,y)=-1+e^xF(2x-y)$$
The function $F$ has to be determined according to the condition $u(x,3x+1)=\sin(x)$

$\sin(x)=-1+e^xF(2x-(3x+1))=1+e^xF(-x-1)$

Let $X=-x-1\quad;\quad x=-X-1$

$\sin(-X-1)=-1+e^{-X-1}F(X)$
$$F(X)=\big(1-\sin(X+1)\big)e^{X+1}$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=2x-y$ :

$$u(x,y)=-1+e^x\big(1-\sin(2x-y+1)\big)e^{2x-y+1}$$
$$u(x,y)=-1+\big(1-\sin(2x-y+1)\big)e^{3x-y+1}$$